# decode list of JSON objects to array of hashes in perl

Tags: arrays, json, perl

I'm a newbie to Perl,I want to parse the following JSON into array of hashes,(map method will be preferred)

```
[
    {   "name" : "Theodor Nelson",
        "id": "_333301",
        "address": "Hello_world"
    },
    {   "name": "Morton Heilig",
        "id": "_13204",
        "address": "Welcome"
     }
    ]
```

then wants to print only "

> name

and

> id

's values in foreach loop. 
any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should check out the [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS) module. There are plenty of examples that describe exactly what you're trying to do. `my $aref = decode_json($str); print "$_->{id}: $_->{name}\n" for @$aref;`

Comment: can you tell me that how can i print the values in view files?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: i mean if i pass the above array of hashes into view file (.tt) file then how can i use /get the values to display that in field

Comment: You'll need to [edit] your question to include some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply do like

```
use JSON qw(encode_json decode_json);

my $JSON = [{   "name" : "Theodor Nelson",
        "id": "_333301",
        "address": "Hello_world },
        {   "name": "Morton Heilig",
        "id": "_13204",
        "address": "Welcome"}]

my $decoded = decode_json $JSON;

return template 'yourtemplate', {
    options =>  $decoded,
        ..,
        ..}
```

and in view file you can access it as `option.id` and `option.name` or `option.address` or whatever is required in FOREACH loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
use JSON qw(from_json);

# The JSON module likes to die on errors
my $json_data = eval { return from_json($json); };
die "$@ while reading JSON" if $@; # Replace by your error handling
die "JSON top level is no array" unless ref($json_data) eq 'ARRAY'; # Replace by your error handling

for my $hashref (@{$json_data}) {
    print $hashref->{name}."\n";
    print $hashref->{id}."\n";
}
```

The error handling is obviously optional depending on your usage case. One-time or manual scripts may just die while production-level scripts should have a proper error handling.

The [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) module is a wrapper for [JSON::PP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::PP) and [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::XS). It selects the module available on the local system. JSON::XS is faster, but might not be installed. JSON::PP is pure Perl (no external C/C++ libraries) and part of the Perl core.

The `for` line [dereferences the *Array-reference*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) representing your top level JSON array. Each item should be a *Hash-reference*. Follow the links for more information on each topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );

my $data = decode_json($json);

$template->process(..., { data => $data }, ...)
   or die(...);
```

Template:

```
[% FOREACH rec IN data %]
   [% rec.id %]: [% rec.name %]
[% END %]
```